# Object localization and text extraction using VGG

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, multilabel-classification, vgg16

I'm new to Computer Vision and training a TensorFlow neural network using VGG16. The problem is quite simple:

I'm training in a custom dataset to detect and localize numbers in a 100x100 image. The numbers (0 to 9) can appear in all x and y within the 100x100 image size. The model works very well when a single object (number) appears.

[image]

However, when I have multiple objects in the image, the model can not handle the task.

[image]

The expected result is something like this:

[image]

How can I do it? The problem is in the `model.predict()` and how I pass the image, but I don't have a clue of what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.

The VGG was not made to detect and localize multiple objects at once. We can do some workaround to make it work like I described earlier, but it's just too complicated and very computationally expensive.

So I decided to move on and use R-CNN and YOLO for multiple object detection and localization. This models are designed for this.

I hope this helps anyone who has the same problem as me.